# Calling an array inside a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm trying to call the values stored in `temp[z]` and then display it using a function. Here is the code:

```
/* File: StudentID_Surname.c  - e.g. 1234567_Wilson.c
 * This program finds the range between highest and lowest value of a 2-D array */

#include <stdio.h>

#define NROW 3
#define NCOL 3

/* Write a function
     void disp_arr(int a[NROW][NCOL]) { ... }
    where a[][] is the 2-D array
    Print the entire array to the screen. */

disp_arr( int temp );

int main(void)
{
    /* declare needed variables or constants, e.g. */
    int ar[NROW][NCOL];
    int rows, cols;
    int z = 0;
    int temp[z] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; /* Storing 9 numbers */

    /* prompt for the user to enter nine positive integers to be stored into the array */

    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ )
    {
        for ( cols = 0 ; cols < 3 ; cols++ )
            {
                printf(  "Please enter 9 positive integers : " );

                scanf( "%d", &ar[rows][cols] );

                /* Store values in the temp[z] = {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}*/
                temp[z] = ar[rows][cols];

                z += 1; /* Increase the array in temp[z] */
            }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /* Call disp_arr to display the 3 x 3 board */
    disp_arr( temp[z] );



}/* end main */

disp_arr( int storedValue )
{
    int x,y;
    for (  x = 0 ; x < 3 ; x++ )
    {
        for (  y = 0 ; y < 3 ; y++ )
        {
            printf( "%d\t", storedValue );
        }
        printf("\n%d");
    }


    return storedValue;
}
```

When I try to execute the code, my compiler gives me the error shown in the attachment. I guess the code `int temp[z] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` was the source of it.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

[image]

Comment: `error shown in the attachment` — I can't find the error in the source code nor in the post, where is it?

Comment: You don't *call* arrays. You define, declare, access or modify them.

Comment: And your code has undefined behavior, even in standards accepting VLA-s. You want `int z=9;` at least.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Actually, he isn't calling the array element, he's calling `disp_arr` with `temp[z]` as the argument.

Comment: Still, the terminology in the title is incorrect.

Comment: @RamchandraApte Sorry I've forgotten the image.

Answer (score 1):

`int temp[z]` is trying to create a [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). `C89` does not support Variable length arrays. Chances are your compiler does not support VLAs - please check the manual. Another problem is that your array size is wrong `int z = 0;`. Due to which you get the warning:

> excess elements in array initializer

Because your array contains 9 elements while you have initialized `z` to `0`. You should have `z` initialized to at least `9`. Also, you are going out of bounds in your loop

```
 temp[z] = ar[rows][cols]; // ---> z goes out of bounds here
```

Initialize `z` to `0` just before loop starts and check for array bounds. Also `printf("\n%d");` expects an argument, like `printf("\n%d", someint);` - if you only intended to print a new line then remove `%d` like this `printf("\n");`

Answer (score 0):

You have very basic errors in your code

1.int temp[z] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; should be

int temp[9]

2.disp_arr( int storedValue )

disp_arr( int* storedValue )

3.disp_arr( temp[z] );

disp_arr(temp)

4.printf(  "Please enter 9 positive integers : " ); should be moved to before nested for loop

Answer (score 0):

In your main code you are trying to
1)create an array of size zero as z =0
2)int z should be constant so that it can be used for creating the array

I think this will do it

```
    int ar[NROW][NCOL];
    int rows, cols;
    const int z = 9; 
    //int temp[z] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; /* Storing 9 numbers */
    //commented the above line and changed the code
    int temp[z] ;
    memset( temp, 0, z*sizeof(int) );

    /* prompt for the user to enter nine positive integers to be stored into the array */
    int index = 0;
    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ )
    {
        for ( cols = 0 ; cols < 3 ; cols++ )
            {
                printf(  "Please enter 9 positive integers : " );

                scanf( "%d", &ar[rows][cols] );

                /* Store values in the temp[z] = {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}*/
                temp[index] = ar[rows][cols];

                index += 1; /* Increase the array in temp[z] */
            }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /* Call disp_arr to display the 3 x 3 board */
    disp_arr( temp[z] );
```

Comment: I still get these errors: [basic links](http://s21.postimg.org/564rrfpav/Error.jpg)

Comment: also you have to change your disp_arr function so that it display all the elements of the array

Comment: i have changed the code check if the code still gives you an error